# Casting an Object to its father class for avoiding its attributes in Java

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, serializable

I have class SuperYo extending class Persona, like this:

```
public class SuperYo extends Persona {

   private NotSerializableObj obj1
   private NotSerializableObj obj2
   private NotSerializableObj obj3

}

public class Persona {

   private SerializableObj sObj1
   private SerializableObj sObj2
   private SerializableObj sObj3

}
```

The thing is, that I add to a LinkedList an Instance of Persona from SuperYo:

```
LinkedList<Persona> list = new LinkedList<Persona>();
list.add((Persona) superYo);
```

It adds it as a SuperYo Object! With all the NonSerializableObjs on it... and thus, cant be sent from a Socket :(.

So, the question is... is there any way of "downcasting" an object to its father class, so its attributtes are non present?

Thanks!

Comment: The behavior you're observing is pretty much the whole point of polymorphism. If you really want to get rid of those fields, you should rethink your design. Perhaps using composition instead of inheritance would be a better idea. A quick workaround would be to provide a method to construct an object of the parent class but it seems like a dirty solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `readObject` and `writeObject` in `SuperYo` as below:

```
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
    //write attributes from PersonYo only
    outStream.defaultWriteObject();
    outStream.writeObject(sObj1);
    outStream.writeObject(sObj2);
    outStream.writeObject(sObj2);
 }

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inStream) throws IOException,
                                                          ClassNotFoundException {
    //read attributes from PersonYo only
    inStream.defaultReadObject();
    sObj1= (SerializableObj)inStream.readObject();
    sObj2= (SerializableObj)inStream.readObject();
    sObj3= (SerializableObj)inStream.readObject();
}
```

Once you do this, there will be no need of down-casting. Also you may have better control on other non-serializable attributes in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is a matter of polymorphism. When you cast an object of type1 to type2, the instance won't change, but you just look at the instance from a new perspective!

If you want to send the child class over the network, you can make the SuperYo members as transient, and fill them on instantiation. Or you can add writeObject() and readObject() methods to your child class.